# "Assignment from distinct type" warning message

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the following warning:

> assignment from distinct objective-c type

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you want help, please include a sample of the code that caused this error.

Comment: This is a similar question, and may provide a clue as to what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079380/objective-c-warning-passing-argument-1-of-touchesforview-from-distinct-object

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get this error, so it's helpful if you post some code...
That said, you're probably doing something like:

```
UIView *bladyblah;
bladyblah = [[MyViewType alloc] init];
```

i.e. assigning an object of one type into a variable of another type.
the fix is either to change the type of the variable, or do a type cast like so:

```
bladyblah = (UIView *)[[MyViewType alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the correctness of the types you are assigning and if needed you have to do an operation of casting! If you post your code it's more easy to help you!